# Preserve character '&' while umarshalling using JAXBContext

Tags: xml, encoding, character-encoding, jaxb

I'm using JAXBContext to unmarshall a XML string. But my code is failing if the string contains '&' character inside a tag. But I need to preserve the value as such.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please show sample xml that's causing your issue.  If your xml contains an unescaped '&', it ain't xml.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
"<category>Play & Boy</category>" this is tag that makes the problem. I need to get the value Play & Boy as such.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment response you have "xml" like

```
<category>Play & Boy</category>
```

This is *not* xml, as the xml rules forbid the use of an unescaped '&' character in this position.

You should change such "xml" to

```
<category>Play &amp; Boy</category>
```

in the source xml so that it is well-formed xml.

It's possible you could encode the "&" as "&" in a preprocessor for this non-well-formed xml, but you'll have to write that preprocessing code yourself, and watch out for escaping '&' characters that are already part of an encoding such as `&amp;` or `&lt;`, as you won't want to convert them to `&amp;amp;` and `&amp;lt;`.

If you can do it, you're better off just getting the supplier of this xml to supply well-formed xml.

Comment: I know this is not a well formed string. Im asking, Is there any way (like any encoding of the string) such that i can unmarshal ths string.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable comments Don.. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities for your Question:

1. Deleting all Spaces before and after &: `<category>Play&Boy</category>` should work.
2. Even better Solution: `<category><![CDATA[Play & Boy]]></category>` will be unmarshalled as  "Play & Boy".